# Coordinate package versions across an organisation

Tags: python, pip, setup.py, distutils, azure-artifacts

I work for a medium sized firm where we have a number ~10 python packages and projects we have developed internally. They partially depend on each other and often have the same package requirements, say `pandas`, `sklearn` etc..

We are now at a stage where contradicting requirements are causing problems as we upgrade various systems.

We use the azure platform and the artifacts feed on it, so any way of fixing the versions there would be the most preferable option, but I hav enot found a way of doing that in the docs, it would appear you must have at least 5 different versions back.

Ideally I'd like to have the requirement files just specify the package name and then set the versions used on upgrade by controlling what versions are available on the server. Is there a nice solution for that?

The options I see are:

- specify pyrc to use a private Pypi server

  - host all packages used on this server so that pypi is never called
  - control the versions on the server
- make requirents.txt a binary that on reading returns a list with the correct versions, updated from some central server.
- An addition to `pip` and `setup.py` that sends the names of packages desired to a central server and gets back a list of version fixed packages as needed.

Any other less faffy ideas?

Comment: I am not entirely sure I understood what you are looking for. Maybe [`constraints.txt` files](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#constraints-files) could help...

Comment: @sinoroc If i haven't misunderstood constraints and requirement files work very similarly.
I'd like to centrally fix what version of various packages is used, so that upgrades can happen in lock step and be controlled from one place rather than 10 different repos.

Comment: I can think of two ways. **1.** Setup and maintain a private index, and make your colleagues use it as their primary index for _pip_ (seems like you have already thought about it). **2.** Maintain a company-wide `constraints.txt` file (not package specific), and make your colleagues (and tools: CI, etc.) feed it to _pip_ on every installation (`pip install Something -c constraints.txt`), so that if a dependency has to be installed and it is listed in `constraints.txt` then the version range restriction from this file applies.

Comment: @sinoroc that is not a bad idea, if i can work out a neat way of feeding the constraints to all repos we might have a winner. I'm thinking git hooks.

Comment: would version locking in `pipenv` or `poetry` be what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, you could keep a copy of `constraints.txt` in each repo and somehow have a CI task that updates all your repos with any new update to `constraints.txt`. But maybe I'd rather keep `constraints.txt` in only one repo, and either pull both or make it a git submodule. Or maybe place the file on a shared file system, and have `pip install Whatever -c /path/to/constraints.txt`. This way it stays global. But it all depends on what fits better in the existing environment and what is more comfortable to your colleagues. All these ideas need to be refined.